# Namenode formatting in hadoop installation

Tags: command-line, bash, dell, inspiron, hadoop

I have given the path for both the configuration files directory and the .sh files directory.

I managed to do the configurations with this path:

root@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:/home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc/hadoop# gedit coresite.xml

```
<configuration>

<!-- In: conf/core-site.xml -->
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/home/hduser/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:54310</value>
  <description>The name of the default file system.  A URI whose
  scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation.  The
  uri's scheme determines the config property (fs.SCHEME.impl) naming
  the FileSystem implementation class.  The uri's authority is used to
  determine the host, port, etc. for a filesystem.</description>
</property>

</configuration>

root@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:/home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc/hadoop# gedit mapred-site.xml

<configuration>

 <!-- In: conf/mapred-site.xml -->
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
  <description>The host and port that the MapReduce job tracker runs
  at.  If "local", then jobs are run in-process as a single map
  and reduce task.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>

root@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:/home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc/hadoop# gedit hdfs-site.xml

<configuration>

 <!-- In: conf/hdfs-site.xml -->
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>Default block replication.
  The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created.
  The default is used if replication is not specified in create time.
  </description>
</property>

</configuration>
```

My directory details:

```
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc$ cd ./hadoop
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc/hadoop$ ls
capacity-scheduler.xml      hadoop-policy.xml        mapred-queues.xml.template
configuration.xsl           hdfs-site.xml            mapred-site.xml
container-executor.cfg      hdfs-site.xml~           mapred-site.xml~
core-site.xml               httpfs-env.sh            mapred-site.xml.template
core-site.xml~              httpfs-log4j.properties  slaves
hadoop-env.cmd              httpfs-signature.secret  ssl-client.xml.example
hadoop-env.sh               httpfs-site.xml          ssl-server.xml.example
hadoop-env.sh~              log4j.properties         yarn-env.cmd
hadoop-metrics2.properties  mapred-env.cmd           yarn-env.sh
hadoop-metrics.properties   mapred-env.sh            yarn-site.xml
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc/hadoop$ cd ..
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc$ ls
hadoop

hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc$ cd ..
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0$ ls
bin  etc  include  lib  libexec  LICENSE.txt  logs  NOTICE.txt  README.txt  sbin  share
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0$ cd ./etc
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc$ ls
hadoop
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/etc$ cd ..
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0$ cd ./sbin
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/sbin$ ls
distribute-exclude.sh  hdfs-config.sh           slaves.sh          start-dfs.cmd        start-yarn.sh     stop-dfs.cmd        stop-yarn.sh
hadoop-daemon.sh       httpfs.sh                start-all.cmd      start-dfs.sh  
       stop-all.cmd      stop-dfs.sh         yarn-daemon.sh
hadoop-daemons.sh      mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh  start-all.sh       start-secure-dns.sh  stop-all.sh       stop-secure-dns.sh  yarn-daemons.sh
hdfs-config.cmd        refresh-namenodes.sh     start-balancer.sh  start-yarn.cmd       stop-balancer.sh  stop-yarn.cmd
```

When I start the daemons:

```
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/sbin$ ls
distribute-exclude.sh    start-all.cmd        stop-all.sh
hadoop-daemon.sh         start-all.sh         stop-balancer.sh
hadoop-daemons.sh        start-balancer.sh    stop-dfs.cmd
hdfs-config.cmd          start-dfs.cmd        stop-dfs.sh
hdfs-config.sh           start-dfs.sh         stop-secure-dns.sh
httpfs.sh                start-secure-dns.sh  stop-yarn.cmd
mr-jobhistory-daemon.sh  start-yarn.cmd       stop-yarn.sh
refresh-namenodes.sh     start-yarn.sh        yarn-daemon.sh
slaves.sh                stop-all.cmd         yarn-daemons.sh
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/sbin$ ./start-all.sh
This script is Deprecated. Instead use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
localhost: starting namenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/logs/hadoop-hduser-namenode-ratan-Inspiron-N5110.out
localhost: starting datanode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/logs/hadoop-hduser-datanode-ratan-Inspiron-N5110.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/logs/hadoop-hduser-secondarynamenode-ratan-Inspiron-N5110.out
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/logs/yarn-hduser-resourcemanager-ratan-Inspiron-N5110.out
localhost: starting nodemanager, logging to /home/hduser/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/logs/yarn-hduser-nodemanager-ratan-Inspiron-N5110.out
hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/sbin$ jps

1441 DataNode
1608 SecondaryNameNode
1912 NodeManager
2448 Jps
1775 ResourceManager

hduser@ratan-Inspiron-N5110:~/hadoop/hadoop-2.4.0/sbin$
```

The problem is I cannot find the namenode that has to be formatted. And when I run the daemons, the namenode is nowhere to be seen. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I have the same problem when I installed hadoop-2.4.0, now I have installed hadoop-1.0.3, Its working properly.. I thing the configuration not proper for latest version...

Answer (score 3):

Check this log file:

> hadoop-hduser-namenode-ratan-Inspiron-N5110.log

If it says namenode is not formatted, format it

> bin/hadoop namenode -format

Answer (score -1):

Check the Storage directory exist or not if yes check the permissions and format the namenode than restrt dfs.It will work..

Thanks